# How to display text when a (multiple)checkbox is checked?

Tags: php, checkbox

This is the snippet in my index:

```
                    <p id="text" style="display:none">hello</p>

 echo '<tr>';
                       echo '<td>'.$s['school_name'].'</td>'; 
                       echo '<td>'.$s['location'].'</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$s['population'].'</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$s['cost'].'</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$s['topnotchers'].'</td>';
                       echo '<td>'.$s['rating'].'</td>';
                       echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="userSelection" name="userSelection" onclick="userSelection()" value="'.$s['school_id'].'"</td>';

                   echo '</tr>';
                   }
```

And here is my js:

```
function userSelection(){

 var checkBox = document.getElementsByName("userSelection")[0];
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
    }
```

}

The text only displays when I check on row[0] since I set it to row[0]. But, what should be done if I need the function to be true to all rows when I check it?
The above code only displays text on first loop. 
Is "*" going to work? 
I'm a beginner, a help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the rest of your code with the loop in it. Also, your question is vague please rephrase so we better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: You don't need Javascript. You can use same name attribute for all your checkboxes as an array like `name="choices[]"` but different value on each checkbox. Then in Php you can loop through and with if statements you can make comparisons. `if (choice[i] === 1) .. ` This video may help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZdkM8A3sJpY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hard coded the index 0. So js function will run only for checkbox with zero index.
First of all change the name of checkboxes to checkbox1, checkbox2,... This will simplify the case.
Then You need to run a for loop for each checkbox. Use
 `

```
for(i=0; i < 6; i++){
   currentCheckBox = document.getElementById("checkbox"+i)
   var text = document.getElementById("text");
   if (currentCheckBox.checked == true){
       text.style.display = "block";
   } else {
       text.style.display = "none";
   }   
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a name as an array like below,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="userSelection1" name="userSelection[]" onclick="userSelection()" value="">
```

Then only you can able to loop in javascript to check the status

```
var checkBoxArr = document.getElementsByName("userSelection[]");
```